# SSLSocket setsockopt returns 10042 and WSAIoctl 10045

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to create a secure socket connection,but I've got some errors.
here is the code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wd;
    SOCKET s;
    SSLVALIDATECERTHOOK hook;
    int secopt=SO_SEC_SSL;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wd);
    s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    setsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SECURE,&secopt,sizeof(secopt));
    hook.HookFunc=SSLValCert;
    hook.pvArg=NULL;
    WSAIoctl(s,SO_SSL_SET_VALIDATE_CERT_HOOK,&hook,sizeof(hook),NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    /* Some code goes here */
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}

int CALLBACK SSLValCert(DWORD dwType,LPVOID pvArg,DWORD dwChainLen,LPBLOB pCertChain,DWORD dwFlags)
{
    return SSL_ERR_OKAY;
}
```

In this code `setsockopt` return 10042 and `WSAIoctl` return 10045.

Comment: Have you checked [what the error codes means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: yes,but I can't understand why this happen?

Comment: Additionally I want to say that, the constants `SO_SECURE`,`SO_SEC_SSL` and `SO_SSL_VALIDATE_CERT_HOOK` is not declared in `winsock2.h` . I have declared them directly in the code. the values are `SO_SECURE=0x2001`, `SO_SEC_SSL=0x2004` and `SO_SSL_VALIDATE_CERT_HOOK=8`

Comment: Some example for these codes [link1](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/36630-ssl-through-winsock/) , [link2](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg21503.html) , [link3](https://lcalligaris.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/implementing-a-secure-socket/) , [link4](http://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.networks.narkive.com/QHtVr5YY/can-winsock-do-https-through-a-proxy) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10042 is `WSAENOPROTOOPT` and 10045 is `WSAEOPNOTSUPP`.  They mean the feature you are trying to use is not supported.

If you read the documentation more carefully, you would see that `SO_SECURE` is only supported on WinCE.  On Windows, if you want the socket to manage security for you, you need to use [Winsock Secure Socket Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394815.aspx) instead.

Otherwise, use an SSL/TLS library that runs on top of a standard socket, such as Microsoft’s [SChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx), or a 3rd party library like [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org).